# Is it possible to use imperial-sized steel coil with metric-sized shock?

Tags: compatibility, shocks, coil

I am looking to build a full-suspension bicycle with coil rear shock. Currently I am considering using a [DVO Jade](https://www.bike24.com/p2308359.html?menu=1000,1868,1918) shock with 55 mm of stroke. The shock is sold without a steel coil, which has to be bought separately to match the rider's weight and riding style.

However, it is strange that I cannot find a nominally matching coil from DVO's options (but see below). There is a slightly larger (2.25", or 57 mm) [coil](https://www.bike24.com/p2140142.html) meant for shocks with imperial units dimensions. I wonder if I can use it instead.

The imperial-units coil is heavier but costs only 15 €. There is indeed a 55 mm version, but it is about 8 times more [expensive](https://www.bike24.com/p2483650.html).

Is this something viable to consider?

Comment: Did you note that the availability of the shock via your link is "unavailable" with most iterations being 11-22 weeks back ordered?

Comment: @Jeff I believe it was in stock a few days ago. I am ready to look elsewhere and/or wait once the compatibility issue is resolved. My question is about the general approach to the metric/imperial units mess existing when shocks and coils are sold separately.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the cheap coil is linear, while the expensive one is progressive. That likely explains the price difference.

In response to the question, the 2mm difference is likely to be well within manufacturing tolerances. Additionally, the preload adjuster has much more than 2mm of room to move, so the coil has to be able to handle at least that much discrepancy.

That said, I don’t have any first-hand experience sizing coil springs and I may be missing something fundamental here, eg. diameter?

Comment: The preload adjuster in this case has 5 mm of official range, I forgot to mention that

Comment: On the diameter — both coils are from the same vendor, for the shock of the same vendor. These coils are not compatible with certain competitors' products, but are compatible with others. But good point about being linear vs non-linear.

Comment: I thought the whole attraction of using coil suspension is the linear aspect of the compression curve? If it's progression u desire, why not use an air shock? (Asking motivated by curiosity not criticism).

Comment: @Jeff Coil shocks have less seal friction than air shocks.

Comment: @Jeff. The coil vs air shock debate is handled elsewhere on many internet platforms, I believe. I am trying to make sure that whichever components I choose play nice with other parts to form a working result. I am considering air shocks as well, but I am also limited by the budget, and current bicycle part situation. The cheapest parts are hard to find, more boutique offerings may be based on coil.